Node 22 + TS 5.4 failed to find module
I have this project set up in this way:
Node 22
TS 5.4
package.json -> type: module
tsconfig.json: {
    "target": "es2022",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "outDir": "app",
    ...
}

When I run the build all the js files are generated in a folder app.
Now, if I start the application with:
npm app/commands/server.js
I get Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module.
I do the import in this way:
import { ApiWorker } from '../core/ApiServer';

but this is not resolved.
I tried to use vite-node but nothing. I tried to change the tsconfig but I couldn't make it work.
node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:257
    throw new ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND(

Any ideas?

You need filename extensions:
import { DarvaWorker } from '../core/ApiServer.js';

TypeScript can work with missing filename extensions and .js instead of .ts, but JavaScript ES modules don't support missing filename extensions.

thanks for replying. Why do I need the extension? It's a fairly big project and changing all import will take a while. It was migrated from some very old dependencies.
I thought that extension wasn't needed

@user1341300 Because ECMA Script doesn't specify default filename extensions.

but if I try to add the extension I get: An import path can only end with a .ts extension when allowImportingTsExtensions is enabled.

@user1341300 And when you disable allowImportingTsExtensions? You haven't mentioned allowImportingTsExtensions in your question.

I get  Option 'allowImportingTsExtensions' can only be used when either 'noEmit' or 'emitDeclarationOnly' is set.

@user1341300 I can't reproduce the problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-sfstkq?file=index.ts It works for me with your posted code after filling the gaps.

The documentation for allowImportingTsExtensions also describes this behavior: "This flag is only allowed when --noEmit or --emitDeclarationOnly is enabled, since these import paths would not be resolvable at runtime in JavaScript output files."
